# How is the slope of one function related to area under the graph of another function?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

So far, I believe I have a clear understanding of integrals and derivatives. If I am not wrong, when we integrate a function(Let's say $f(x)$), we find its anti-derivative(say $F(x)$). But what I fail to understand is the logical/mathematical relation between and integral and a derivative.

In other words, How is the derivative of one function giving us the integral of another? What exactly is the relationship?

Let us take a simple example of $f(x) = 3x^2$,whose indefinite integral is $x^3$. So why is $x^3$'s derivative giving us $3x^2$'s integral?

Comment: This is just the underlying result of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: The area under $3x^2$ is related to $x^3,$ and the instantaneous rate of change of the area is $3x^2$

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnJqaIESC2s Might give you some intuition.

Comment: I think you are confused.  The derivative of $x^3 = 3x^2$ which is *NOT* the integral of $3x^2$.  It *IS* $3x^2$.  And the integral of $3x^2$ is not *the derivative* of $x^3$.  It *IS* $x^3$ (plus a constant).

Comment: "But what I fail to understand is the logical/mathematical relation between and integral and a derivative."  You just answered that yourself in the previous sentence: "when we integrate a function, we find its anti-derivative".  That's it entirely.  Then you ask "How is the derivative of one function giving us the integral of another"  But it doesn't!  Is gives us the other function.  Not the integral of the other function.  *It* (the original function) is the integral of the function-- not its derivative.  The derivative is the other function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative doesn't give you the integral of an other function.  The derivative gives you a function that has the first function as an integral.

The derivative of $x^3$ is not $3x^2$'s integral.  It is $3x^2$.  It's that$3x^2$'s integral is the original $x^3$.

The relationship is if:

$F'(x) = f(x)$ then  $\int f(x) dx = F(x)$.

basically (and theres a lot of technicalities I'm ignoring about whether derivatives/integrals exist and the whole "plus a constance" equivalence between classes of integers) derivatives and integrals are inverses.

$(\int f(x) dx)' = f(x)$ and $\int f'(x) dx = f(x) + C$.

If $F(x) = x^3$ and $f(x) =3x^2$ then $F'(x) = f(x)$  (*not* $\int f(x) dx$ as you said several times)  and $\int f(x) dx = F(x) + C$.

Why?  Well that's another question.

=====

We'll the derivative of $x^3$ *is* the integral of *another* function.  $(x^3)'  = \int 6x dx$.

That is, the derivative is the integral of the *double* derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if we assume $f$ to be continuous, the relationship between $f$ and its integral, $F$, is given by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which asserts that, if $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous, then $F:[a,b]:\to\mathbb R$ given by
$$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt
$$
is differentiable and $F'(c) = f(c)$ for all $c\in[a,b]$. We can easily read this result as *on an interval where $f$ is continuous, the area between the curve of $f$ ($F$) and the horizontal axis grows/decreases at a rate described by $f$*.

This is the reason why we say that $F$ is the primitive of $f$.